# Apache Airflow with SQL Server database and logging

Tags: sql-server, logging, airflow

I have Microsoft SQLServer based stored procedure say `sp1` which has print statements.

Like below -

```
print 'Task1 has finished'
print 'Task2 has finished'
```

I would like this print statement to show up in Apache Airflow after airflow triggers `sp1` and these print statements should show up in the view log for that stored procedure.

If we execute a python operator all the print statements show up in log but not when you run a Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure on Apache Airflow.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Exec sp1
```